# Branching graph of $\mathbb{C}S_{n}$, if $T$ is path $V_T=W_0\to W_1\to\cdots\to W_n$, why does $\mathbb{C}S_k\cdot V_T=W_k$?

Tags: group-theory, modules, representation-theory, symmetric-groups

Let $\mathbb{B}$ be the branching graph whose vertices are isomorphism classes of all irreducible $\mathbb{C}S_n$, $n\geq 0$ modules, with an edge $W\to V$ if the iso class of a $\mathbb{C}S_n$-module $W$ occurs as a composition factor of the $\mathbb{C}S_{n+1}$-module $V$. Since restriction from $S_n$ to $S_{n-1}$ of an irreducible module is multiplicity free, there is a canonical decomposition
$$
\operatorname{res}_{S_0}V=\bigoplus_T V_T
$$
where $V_T$ is an irreducible $\mathbb{C}S_0=\mathbb{C}$-module, and $T$ runs over paths $V_T=W_0\to W_1\to\cdots\to W_n=V$ in $\mathbb{B}$.

The text I'm reading, (Linear and Projective Representations of symmetric groups by Kleshchev, p. 9) says that $\mathbb{C}S_k\cdot V_T=W_k$. Why is the true? I don't understand what it means for $S_k$ to act on $V_T$ if $V_T$ is only a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space, and why is would give you a certain module in the path $T$ in the branching graph.

Comment: $V_T$ is a subspace of the $\mathbb{C}S_n$-module $V$ (or even $\mathbb{C} S_{n+1}$-module $V$, depending on the notations), so in particular any subalgebra of $\mathbb{C}S_n$ can be "multiplied" by it. The result, of course, doesn't have to stay inside $V_T$, but will stay inside $V$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Thanks, that makes the multiplication $\cdot$ make sense. In particular $\mathbb{C}S_k\cdot V_T\subseteq W_k$, and since it's a $\mathbb{C}S_k$-submodule and $W_k$ is irreducible, the claimed equality follows?

Comment: Probably. I am not sure -- the Bratelli picture is confusing to me.

Comment: @JoieHwang That's right: since $V_T \subseteq W_k$ and $W_k$ is irreducible, then $\mathbb{C}S_k \cdot V_T = W_k$.